# Regarding radius of convergence of power series.

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

This is a question from a past exam. Let $f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$. Find the power series representation of $f$ centered at $1$ and its radius of convergence.

**My solution:** Notice that (it was given as a hint)
$$
f(z)=\frac{i}{2}\left[\frac{1}{1+i} \cdot \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{z-1}{1+i}\right)}-\frac{1}{1-i}\cdot \frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{z-1}{1-i}\right)}\right]
$$
Then I expanded the fractions using the geometric series. To find the radius of convergence in this particular case is easy. First, notice that for $|z-1| < |1+i|=\sqrt{2}$ the series converges to $f(z)$ so the radius $R$ must be greater than or equal to $\sqrt{2}$. Next notice that the distance of $1$ from the singularities at $\pm i$ should be greater than or equal to $R$ so $R \leq \sqrt{2}$. Putting it all together we get $R = \sqrt{2}$.

First of all, is my solution correct? If yes then I wonder how to solve such problems if we can't get both inequalities. Calculating the $\limsup$ of the coefficients can be quite difficult so what is a good way to approach them? Is it to try and write $f$ as the sum of terms of the form
$$\frac{1}{1 \pm \frac{z-a}{a-z_k}}$$
where $z_k$ are the singularities of $f$ (where $a$ denotes the center)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The power series centered at which point?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry for that. I edited my post. It's centered at $a=1$

Comment: Short answer: the poles are $\pm i$ hence the disk of convergence will be centered at $1$ and pass through $\pm i$ (radius $\sqrt2$).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Well I know that for a holomorphic function $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ and every $R$ such that $D(a, R) \subseteq \Omega$ we can expand $f$ as a power series centered at $a$ and with radius $R$ but in this case the problem asks for a particular expansion. Is it true that every expansion will have radius equal to the minimum distance from the singularities?

Comment: If you decompose the rational function in simple fractions, a term like $\dfrac1{(z-z_0)+(z_0-z_p)}$ (i.e. pole at $z_p$, development around $z_0$) develops as as sum of powers of $\dfrac{z-z_0}{z_0-z_p}$. You can conclude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of determining the radius of convergence has a problem. If you have two power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(z-a)^n$ with the same radius of convergence $R$, it is not true in general that the radius of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n+b_n)(z-a)^n$ is also $R$. It has to be *at least* $R$, but it can be larger (as when $b_n$ is always equal to $-a_n$).

In this case it is $\sqrt2$ because if it was larger and if your Taylor series was $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n$, then the limit $\lim_{z\to i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n$ would exist (in $\Bbb C$); it would be $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(i-1)^n$. But, on the other hand,$$\lim_{z\to i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n=\lim_{z\to i}\frac1{z^2+1},$$and this limit does not exist (in $\Bbb C$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am confused. Isn't it a requirement that the disk of convergence is contained inside the domain of the function?

Comment: Why? If $f\colon D_1(0)\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ is the null function, then its Taylor series centered at $0$ is the null series, whose radius of convergence is $\infty$.

Comment: I see. So the disk of convergence must avoid poles right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It makes sense considering that a function without negative powers in its Laurent series cannot have a pole. Thanks again!